# What HTTP status codes to return on wrong API versions?

Tags: rest, api, http, versioning, api-versioning

I'm designing a simple versioned RESTful API. The version will be specified as part of the media type in the `Accept` header. I wonder what are the proper HTTP status codes for these cases:

- version **not yet** supported, e.g.

  ```
  Accept: application/json; version=999.0
  ```
- version **no longer** supported

  ```
  Accept: application/json; version=0.1
  ```

Comment: here's a [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) for choosing the appropriate HTTP Status Code

Comment: You can't attach a parameter to media type (content-type) where you don't control the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you should use `406 Not Acceptable` for both cases.

> 406 Not Acceptable The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

Answer (score 1):

According to ASP.NET repo, that would either be `400` or `405`, depending on the situation:

| Status Code | Error Code | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | ApiVersionUnspecified | An API version is required, but was not specified |
| 400, 405 | UnsupportedApiVersion | The specified API version is not supported |
| 400 | InvalidApiVersion | An API version was specified, but it is invalid |
| 400 | AmbiguousApiVersion | An API version was specified multiple times with different values |

For more info see: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Error-Responses